# Existence of minimal subcover for any open cover of a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space. Does every open cover of $X$ have a minimal subcover with respect to inclusion?

In other words:

> If $\mathcal{O}$ is an open cover of a metric space $X$, then does there exist an open cover $\mathcal{U} \subseteq \mathcal{O}$ such that, if $\mathcal{U}' \subsetneq \mathcal{U}$, then $\mathcal{U}'$ does **not** cover $X$ ?

Comment: Do you mean minimal in the sense of the cardinality, or minimal in the sense of no sub-subcover exists?

Comment: I meant the sub-subcover sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any $x\in X$, and consider the covering by the sets $\{y\in X:d(x,y)<n\}$ for all positive integers $n$. If $X$ is unbounded (with respect to the metric $d$), then this open cover has no minimal subcover.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now what if X is bounded?

Comment: @infinitesimal take $\mathbb R$ with the metric $d(x,y) = \min\{1,|x-y|\}$ and consider the cover by the intervals $(-a,a)$. I'd have to think harder if you said that $X$ was totally bounded.

Comment: And by think harder I mean: The same argument works just fine for the interval $(-1,1)$.

Comment: @kahen Thanks. I'm now wondering why I was trying so badly to prove the statement, and how I missed these counterexamples.

Answer (score 6):

As other answers have pointed out, there are easy counterexamples. What **is** true is that if $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of a metric space $X$, then $\mathscr{U}$ has an irreducible open *refinement*: that is, there is an open cover $\mathscr{R}$ of $X$ such that

1. for each $R\in\mathscr{R}$ there is a $U\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $R\subseteq U$, and
2. for each $R\in\mathscr{R}$, the family $\mathscr{R}\setminus\{R\}$ no longer covers $X$.

This is a consequence of two well-known theorems. First, every metric space is paracompact, so every open cover of a metric space has a locally finite open refinement. Secondly, every point finite cover of a set (and *a fortiori* every locally finite cover) has an irreducible subcover.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\mathbb R$ and $U_n=(-n,n)$. Then $\{U_n\}$ covers $X$ but it doesn't have a minimal sub-cover.